# Proof of the Addition and Scalar multiplication for linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f, g : U\rightarrow V$ be linear maps and  $\lambda\in  F$. Then the maps
$f + g : U\rightarrow V$ and $\lambda f : U \rightarrow V$ are linear.

> My attempt at the proof for the first statement is as follows:
>
> Let $u,z\in U$ and $a\in F$, using a linearity check
>
> by deﬁnition of $f + g$
> $$(f + g)(au + z) = f(au + z) + g(au + z)$$ by linearity of $f$ and $g$
>
> $$= (af(u) + f(z)) + (ag(u) + g(z)) $$ by basic properties of vector spaces
>
> $$= af(u) + ag(u) + f(z) + g(z)$$ by an axiom of vector spaces
>
> $$= a(f(u) + g(u)) + (f(z) + g(z))$$ by deﬁnition of $f + g$.
>
> $$= a(f + g)(u) + (f + g)(z)$$ Hence, $f + g$ is linear

Is this the correct approach. What is the proof of $\lambda f : U \rightarrow V$ to be linear?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Do the same for $(\lambda f)(x)=\lambda f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
(\lambda f)(u+av)=\lambda f(u+av)=\lambda (f(u)+af(v))=\lambda f(u)+a\lambda f(v)
=(\lambda f)(u)+a(\lambda f)(v). %Comment added into order to correct one character typo.
$$